# FacetGrid returned seaborn's relplot does not respect hue

Tags: python, seaborn, facet-grid, relplot

I am encountering a problem in which seaborn's `relplot` function creates a `FacetGrid` that is different from creating the `FacetGrid` manually. I find this unintuitive and would like the `relplot` function to give me a `FacetGrid` that behaves similarly to the manually created one.

The issue is that when using the `map` function on the `FacetGrid` returned from `relplot`, it does not consider a specified hue anymore. Here is a minimal example that explains my point:

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

def foo(color=None, label=None, tag=None):
    print(tag, color, label)

x = np.random.randn(100)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x' : x,
    'y' : 2 * x,
    'row' : np.random.randn(x.shape[0]) > 0,
    'col' : np.random.randn(x.shape[0]) > 0,
    'hue' : np.random.randn(x.shape[0]) > 0,
})
g = sns.relplot(data = df, x = 'x', y = 'y', row='row', col='col', hue='hue')
g.map(foo, tag='relplot')

g2 = sns.FacetGrid(data = df, row = 'row', col = 'col', hue='hue')
g2.map(foo, tag='FacetGrid')
```

When calling the `map` function on the facet grid returned by `relplot`, it will only be called four times (once per row and column) but will not respect the fact that I also specified a hue. The output is:

```
relplot (0.2980392156862745, 0.4470588235294118, 0.6901960784313725) None
relplot (0.2980392156862745, 0.4470588235294118, 0.6901960784313725) None
relplot (0.2980392156862745, 0.4470588235294118, 0.6901960784313725) None
relplot (0.2980392156862745, 0.4470588235294118, 0.6901960784313725) None
```

If I map the same function to the `FacetGrid` that is manually created, it will result in the expected behaviour:

```
FacetGrid (0.2980392156862745, 0.4470588235294118, 0.6901960784313725) False
FacetGrid (0.8666666666666667, 0.5176470588235295, 0.3215686274509804) True
FacetGrid (0.2980392156862745, 0.4470588235294118, 0.6901960784313725) False
FacetGrid (0.8666666666666667, 0.5176470588235295, 0.3215686274509804) True
FacetGrid (0.2980392156862745, 0.4470588235294118, 0.6901960784313725) False
FacetGrid (0.8666666666666667, 0.5176470588235295, 0.3215686274509804) True
FacetGrid (0.2980392156862745, 0.4470588235294118, 0.6901960784313725) False
FacetGrid (0.8666666666666667, 0.5176470588235295, 0.3215686274509804) True
```

Is there any explanation as to why that happens? Is there a way to change `relplot`'s behaviour to match the expected one, i.e. to respect the hue parameter I set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any explanation as to why that happens?

Yes, in `relplot` the `hue` logic is all handled within `scatterplot`, not by the `FacetGrid`.

> Is there a way to change relplot's behaviour to match the expected one?

No, in this case you'll want to make your custom function handle the hue logic internally or start with `FacetGrid` directly.